# How to change the input name in Vue.js?

Tags: php, html, vue.js

I'd like to use dynamic form.
and input name have to be array. then have to add array number by automatic for post.

The following is my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title></title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css"integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz"crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
            <div id="sample">
                <button v-on:click="addNewItemForm">New Item</button>
                <div v-for="(item, index) in items">
                    <span style="coursor:pointer" v-on:click="deleteItemForm(index)">close</span>
                    <div>
                        <div>number({{index+1}})</div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Title:</label>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" name="title[{{index}}]" required placeholder="here is title" v-model="item.title">
                                <p class="alert-warning">{{item.title}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Detail:</label>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" name="detail[{{index}}]" required placeholder="here is detail" v-model="item.detail">
                                <p>{{item.detail}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center mt-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success px-3">Register</button>
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

</body>

</html>

<script>
    var app = new Vue ({
        name:'Sample-app',
        el:'#sample',
        data:{
            items:[
                {
                    title:'',
                    detail:''
                }
            ]
        },
        methods:{
            addNewItemForm(){
                this.items.push({
                    title:'',
                    detail:''
                })
            },
            deleteItemForm(index){
                this.items.splice(index,1)
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

here is link in code pen.
You can check this form.
[https://codepen.io/takudemo/pen/NWPBYMe?fbclid=IwAR3bpfc3IuI6cz7Y02ZgGGetDkDIHb5aC4op4earENzKYIkftPE2ZzzI51Q]
and I tried like this.

```
<div>
 <input type="text" name="title[{{index}}]" required placeholder="here is title" v-model="item.title">
 <p class="alert-warning">{{item.title}}</p>
</div>
```

also detail.

but It's not working.
and The following is error message.

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

name="title[{{index}}]": Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div id="{{ val }}">, use <div :id="val">.

8  |                              <label>Title:</label>
9  |                              <div>
10 |                                  <input type="text" name="title[{{index}}]" required="" placeholder="here is title" v-model="item.title">
   |                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
11 |                                  <p class="alert-warning">{{item.title}}</p>
12 |                              </div>
```

If  you have any ideas that to solve it.
Please let me know.

Comment: The no of items is dynamic, Each item has title and detail .  When add item button is pressed there should be fields to add a button . Is this what you are trying to do

Comment: Are you new to vue? You use v-bind for this stuff and then save that in ur data object....

Comment: Yes,I'm new to vue.
BTW,I solved by this code.
                                <input type="text" v-bind:name="'name[' + index + ']'" required placeholder="here is title" v-model="item.title">

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I wil close this question.

Comment: If you have another ideas.Please let me know.I want to know for improving.and I want to help for beginer in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you want to set some attribute dynamically in VueJS use `:`.

Second, even if you try `:name="title[index]"` it won't work because you don't have `title` array in your `data`. You have only `items` array. Add `title` and `detail` arrays in 'data' if you want to set names from them.

But I suppose that you want to generate names with `title` and `detail` properties of the corresponding item.

So, instead of this: `name="detail[{{index}}]"` and `name="detail[{{index}}]"` 
use this: `:name="item.title"` and `:name="item.detail"`.

And also save something to `title` and `detail` in `addNewItemForm` to see the changes, for example, like this:

```
 addNewItemForm(){
                this.items.push({
                    title:'title' + (this.items.length+1),
                    detail:'detail' + (this.items.length+1)
                })
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample code.
I couldn't imagine this way.
But I can't get name with array.
For example, this is a result from second title input 「name="title2"」
even first title input name is empty.

I could solve by this code. <input type="text" v-bind:name="'name[' + index + ']'" required placeholder="here is title" v-model="item.title">

Comment: But I appreciate you to help me.
I'm new to vue also javascript.
I could know another way to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing here is that you want to dynamically set a tag attribute. In order to achieve that you need the `:` or `v-bind:` syntax. On top of that an html attribute is always a string. Hence, having these 2 things in mind what you are looking for is:

```html
<input type="text" :name="`title[${index}]`"
 required="" placeholder="here is title" v-model="item.title">
```

P.S.:Having that said, I would reconsider using that name as it feels you are trying to use a javascript object while it is purely a string.

Comment: Thank you for you reply and sample code.
I didn't know that way to solve this problem.
That's right.I wanted to get value that is purely a string.
and then I solved by this code.
<input type="text" v-bind:name="'name[' + index + ']'" required placeholder="here is title" v-model="item.title">
I appreciate you to help me.